# Okta SSO using OIDC

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-api

we are using Okta authentication for our application, now we need to use okta single sign-on (SSO)
When we log in okta then we are showing the assigned apps. Now when we click on the apps then we need to redirect to the dashboard without authentication. can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you have any particular issue? Will you be able to show a code snippet, which is not working for you?

Comment: I don't have any particular code snippet, write now when we click on the app at that time its automatically redirects to the login page but we need to login without credentials. can you help me with any sample code?

Comment: I'd recommend you to start with https://developer.okta.com ,and see some examples, depending on the stack you are using. When you have more specific questions, you can come back for them to be addressed by the community. At this point you need a guide or a mentor to get you started